# In Hollowviews, how do I get grid lines to line up with tick marks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, holoviews

[image]

When I change the xticks in hollowviews, the grid lines sill line up with the default xticks. How can I get the grid to line up with my custom xticks?

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')
points = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]
%opts Curve  [xticks=[0,1.5,9] show_grid=True]
hv.Curve(points)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if this is still relevant, you would have to convert it to a Bokeh figure and then utilize Bokeh functions like this.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models.tickers import FixedTicker
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')

%opts Curve [xticks=[0, 1.5, 9] show_grid=True]

points = [(0.1 * i, np.sin(0.1 * i)) for i in range(100)]
plot = hv.Curve(points)
p = renderer.get_plot(plot).state
p.xgrid[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[1.5, 9])
show(p)
```

[Specific Tick Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94v75.png)

Comment: I created an extension mod to do this in a more straightforward manner. https://holoext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/set_fixed_xticks_yticks_desired_axis.html